# Flow data between 2 tabs of the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I opened the same page in different tabs with different mode and when I pressed one of the button that should fill the inputs, the data filled in the last tab opened, not the tab that has been clicked.
The angular input:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="Type"
       style="width:170px;text-align:auto"
       ng-model="This_Page.Data.Type"
       ng-disabled="This_Page.Action == 'View'"
       autocomplete="off">
```

code:

```
$scope.This_Page.Data.Type = l_Details.Type;
```

what should I do to ensure that every tab get only it's data?

**EDIT 1:**

I guess my question was not clear enough...

I have an application that is built based on TABs, each with its own controller assigned, that open upon request. Some of the tabs serve for dual behavior (same HTML, same Controller code): Create an element (e.g. User Login credentials) and Edit an element (Edit User Credentials).

The issue is that when I open two instances of the same tab, whatever I enter in one of the tabs ***leaks*** to the other instance of the same tab.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use: `ng-model` for binding inputs in single page.

Comment: I don't understand.... its the same page only 2 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: 
You can bind with : `{{}}` and in js return html with : `${}`

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

  function AppCtrl ( $scope ) {
    $scope.data = {
      selectedIndex: 0,
      firstDataSet: "First Data set",
      secondDataSet:   "Second Data set"
    };
    
    $scope.selectedTab = function(index) {
      if(index === 'one')
        return $scope.data.firstDataSet;
      if(index === 'two')
        return $scope.data.secondDataSet;
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.tabsdemoStaticTabs md-tab-content {
  padding: 25px; }
  .tabsdemoStaticTabs md-tab-content:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #42A5F5; }
  .tabsdemoStaticTabs md-tab-content:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #689F38; }
  .tabsdemoStaticTabs md-tab-content:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #26C6DA; }

.tabsdemoStaticTabs .after-tabs-area > span {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 35px; }

.tabsdemoStaticTabs .after-tabs-area > md-checkbox {
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 0; }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="tabsdemoStaticTabs" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="data.selectedIndex">
      <md-tab id="1" md-on-select="resultOne = selectedTab('one')">
        <md-tab-label>
          <h3>My Tab content</h3>
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          <p>
        {{ resultOne }}
          </p>
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab id="2" md-on-select="resultTwo = selectedTab('two')">
        <md-tab-label>
          <h3>My Tab content</h3>
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          <p>
            {{ resultTwo }}
          </p>
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>


</div>
```